# ASP.Net Web Api Help page moved to another project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have a `WebApi` Service with a Help Area. For security reasons, I need to move this `MVC` Help Area to another `MVC` Project in the same solution.

How can be achieved this?

I understand that the `API` info is getting by an `XML` File, but is just move the Area and the `XML` File?